# Многопоточный стек (как динамическая структура данных) на Си - это как?

Tags: c, многопоточность, стек

получил задание **написать стек на атомиках (т.е. с использованием _atomic built-in's)**. Начал с того, что в целом познакомился со стеком, как динамической структурой данных, и написал его простой однопоточный вариант, основанный на массиве:

```
    #define INIT_SIZE 10 //начальный размер массива
    #define MULTIPLIER 2 //коэффициент, на который будет умножаться size  в случае (top>size)
    #define STACK_IVERFLOW -100
    #define STACK_UNDERFLOW -101
    #define OUT_OF_MEMORY -102
    
typedef struct Stack_tag {
    T* data;//указатель на данные
    size_t size;//размер стека
    size_t top;//число элементов в стеке и указатель на вершину
    } Stack_t;
...
Stack_t* createStack() {
    Stack_t* out = NULL;
    out = (Stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(Stack_t));
    if (out == NULL)
        exit(OUT_OF_MEMORY);
    out->size = INIT_SIZE;
    out->data = (T*)calloc(out->size, sizeof(T));
    if (out->data == NULL) {
        free(out);
        exit(OUT_OF_MEMORY);
    }
    out->top = 0;
    return out;
}
void deleteStack(Stack_t** stack) {
    free((*stack)->data);
    free(*stack);
    *stack = NULL;
}

void resize(Stack_t *stack) {
    stack->size *= MULTIPLIER;
    stack->data = (T*)realloc(stack->data, stack->size * sizeof(T));
    if (stack->data == NULL) {
        exit(STACK_OVERFLOW);
    }
}

void push(Stack_t *stack, T value) {
    if (stack->top >= stack->size) {
        resize(stack);
    }
    stack->data[stack->top] = value;
    stack->top++;
}
```

Мой вопрос заключается в том, что

1. не совсем понимаю как стек перестроить под многопоточность (правильно ли понимаю, что многопоточный стек - это когда "много тредов пишут в стек какие-то значения и много тредов читают их в стек"?),
2. для чего здесь атомарные переменные и атомарные функции, как их сюда приспособить? (Для того ли они нужны, чтобы два потока ненароком в одно и то же место в стеке не писали?)

Спасибо!

Comment: 0. Когда изменяете размер, не делайте это на каждый "чих",  а добавляйте некоторое количество сразу (например, по 8 элементов). 1. Да, вам надо обеспечить целостность данных на время записи и чтения стека. 2. Насчёт функций не уверен, а атомарным у вас должен быть указатель на вершину. Тогда у вас всегда будет происходить корректная запись в стек, вот с чтением уже интереснее, ну и с выделением места под новые элементы.